# Finding Max in SqLite using SQLitePCL-WP8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I'm very new to integrating SQlite to Universal Apps. I have got the db up and running. But now I'm trying to find the Max of a Column. Its not returning the expected value. The Db is populated with data

```
var db = App.conn;
using (var statement = db.Prepare("SELECT MAX(Priority) as Priority FROM FOLDER; "))
{
    statement.Step();
    var result = (int)statement["Priority"];
}
```

The exception says wrong casting but Priority is of Integer type.

**EDIT**

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in JusWrite Trial.WindowsPhone.exe but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Post the actual error message. Also I assume you get exception in this line `(int)statement["Priority"]`. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes thts where its crashed. I have updated the exception

Comment: Ok, Try `Console.WriteLine(statement["Priority"].GetType());` and update the post what it prints

Comment: It returnss Int64. converted to int32. If you could post you answer , I will mark it. Thanks!

Comment: Posted as answer, basically problem is with boxing, You will not be able to cast boxed `Int64` to `Int32`. if it is not boxed then everything is perfectly fine. Refer my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is an alias for `Int32` not `Int64` hence `int != Int64`. You can only cast a boxed struct to same type or its Nullable variant. In this case it happens to be long/Int64 or Nullable aka `long?`.

To fix this, you either need a cast to `long` before casting to `int` or simply use `Convert.ToInt32`

```
var result = (int)(long)statement["Priority"];
```

or

```
var result = Convert.ToInt32(statement["Priority"]);
```

Further reading [Representation and Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx)

Comment: Or perhaps just cast to long: `var result = (long)statement...`